# Concatenate the two strings side by side separated by a space?

Tags: python, string, file, loops, concatenation

I want to concatenate two strings side by side. However, when I run my code the strings are saved one below the other. I want it to be side by side separated by a space.

```
path = '../data/img'
mask = '../data/canny_mask'
text_file = open("train.lst", "w")
for file in os.listdir(path):
    img_name = file[:]

for file in os.listdir(mask):
    mask_name = file[:]
    text_file.write(str('data/img')+str(img_name)+'\n')+text_file.write(str('data/canny_mask')+str(mask_name)+'\n')

text_file.close()
```

Comment: You should show your input and outout.

Answer (score 3):

Here, you are calling `text_file.write()` twice:

```
text_file.write(str('data/img')+str(img_name)+'\n')+text_file.write(str('data/canny_mask')+str(mask_name)+'\n')
```

In the first call, there's a newline character `'\n'`. If you want a space instead of a newline, change the code at that point.

I also recommend to not put a `+` between the two calls. Write them in separate lines, or make only one call.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might help:

```
for file in os.listdir(mask):
    mask_name = file[:]
    " ".join('data/img', str(img_name), 'data/canny_mask', str(mask_name))
```